# "Array to String Conversion Error" in laravel blade file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have an `$array_variable` like that in my laravel controller:

```
{"11161":{"total":1,"1":1,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0},"11160":{"total":1,"1":1,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0},"11159":{"total":5,"1":5,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0},"11158":{"total":1,"1":1,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0},"11157":{"total":2,"1":2,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0},"11156":{"total":2,"1":2,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0},"11155":{"total":1,"1":1,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0},"11154":{"total":2,"1":2,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0},"11153":{"total":1,"1":1,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0},"11152":{"total":2,"1":2,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0},"11151":{"total":2,"1":2,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0},"11137":{"total":2,"1":2,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0},"11150":{"total":2,"1":2,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0},"11136":{"total":2,"1":2,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0},"11135":{"total":1,"1":1,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0},"11132":{"total":2,"1":2,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0},"11134":{"total":2,"1":2,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0},"11133":{"total":2,"1":2,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0},"11121":{"total":2,"1":2,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0},"11120":{"total":1,"1":1,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0},"11119":{"total":1,"1":0,"2":1,"3":0,"4":0}}
```

When I access it in blade file via `{{ $array_variable[$id] }}` or `{{ $array_variable }}`, it gives this error:

```
ErrorException
Array to string conversion
```

How can I access array elements without error?

Comment: Depends on what operation you are trying on the array (assigning, printing etc). Can you share the accessing line?

Comment: Access lines are given: {{ $array_variable[$id] }} and {{ $array_variable }}.

Comment: `{{ $array_variable[$id] }}` is giving you `array("total" => 1, "1" => 1, ...)`. You should give us more info about your expected output.

Answer (score 2):

When you get `$array_variable[$id]` it gives you a subquery of:

```
"total" => [(...)]
```

which isn't string. So that why you getting this error. The `{{ (...) }}` statement is for echoing data and when you try to echo array you get this error. You can give a try with something like this:

```
{{ 'total: ' . implode(', ', $array_variable[$id]['total']) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like an array, but a json object.. in either case you cannot echo that. What you can do is: json_decode() it and then a for/each loop over it to echo the elements.

Comment: It isn't json. It is initiated with _$array_variable = array();_ line in controller, then _$array_variable["total"] = 0;_ line is executed for example.

Comment: Correction: It isn't json. It is initiated with _$array_variable = array();_ line,  I initiated a temp array secondly. After filling temp array _$array_variable[id] = temp_array;_ line is executed for instance.

Answer (score -1):

use var_dump for printing arrays

```
var_dump($array_variable[$id]);
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? How does dumping an array solve the given question?